# Implementing a logical condition in pyparsing

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

I have been working on implementing parsing and evaluating a condition using pyparsing.
My goal is to be able to successfully parse an expresion of the type:

x < 10 AND y > 5 AND z < 3

The code I came up with is something like this:

```
    var = Word(alphas + '._', alphanums + '._')
    text = Suppress("'") + Word(alphas, alphanums) + Suppress("'")
    integer = Word(nums).setParseAction(lambda t: int(t[0]))
    operator = oneOf(">= <= != > < ==")
    comperison = (var + operator + (integer | text)).setParseAction(lambda t: self.operands_map[t[1]](t[0], t[2]))

     expr = operatorPrecedence(binary_op,[
                        ("NOT", 1, opAssoc.RIGHT, lambda t: do_not(t)),
                        ("OR", 2, opAssoc.LEFT, do_or(t)),
                        ("AND", 2, opAssoc.LEFT, lambda t: do_and(t))])
```

When I have no logical conditions or just one logical it works fine but when I have more then one as in the exammple I gave above it seems to fail and doesn't even to the logical operations.

Can someone here provide some insights or guidance? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm aassuming `operands_map` maps the comparison operators to little functions that take two arguments. Make sure that you convert the variable name `X`, `Y`, or `Z` to its actual value, else you'll be comparing the string 'X' with the integer 10, etc.

Comment: A good start at your parser, here are some other tips: your current definition of var will accept `...` or even just `.` as a variable name. If the '.'s are meant to be operators to get member values, then a better var would be `delimitedList(Word(alphas+'_', alphanums+'_'), '.', combine=True)`. Also your definition of text as a string inside single quotes will not accept any spaces in the string - pyparsing defines `sglQuotedString` that handles a number of quoting issues. And the parse action for "OR" should be `lambda t: do_or(t)`, not just `do_or(t)`.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire Thank you for the advices I fixed the problem with the OR operator. 
I actually have also an action set on the var so it will look up the value real value based on a context.
The operands_map does implement the comparison operators and I have good unit test coverage so I know those operators are working. 
Based on other questions I saw on the site this should work but from what I am seeing once I add more then one logical operator the parser stops after the first comparison and returns that result.

Comment: Actually debugging it some more the problem was indeed with how I was looking up the value for the variable. It seems that when the method set in setParseAction returns None the parser still sets the original string and not None. Thank you for pointing me to the right path @PaulMcGuire.

Comment: If you need a parse action to return `None`, return `[None]`